# How to update route if nextprops is different than this.props

Tags: reactjs, redirect, redux, react-router

I've got a list and multiple list items, and a details panel to the right that shows details about the selected item. when an item is clicked, it updates the route and, thus, updates the details in the panel. What I want to happen is - when I delete an item from the list it automatically updates the route so that it selects the next item in the list and shows it's details. here's a very basic structure;

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps: props) { 
    if(nextProps.id !== this.props.id){
    this.setState({example: true})
    }
}

doSomething = () => {
    // a function that will delete an item and cause redux to update and map
    my state to my props, causing the updated list to render
}

return(
this.state.example ? <Redirect to={`${newItemsRoute}`} /> : <button onClick={this.doSomething}
)

const mapStateToProps = (state: StoreState, ownProps: any) => {
return {
...ownProps
 };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(DomainResponsePage);
```